# Building React Native Android app causes error "Cannot add task [...] as a task with that name already exists."

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, react-native

When I build my React Native project, I'm getting this error (`AwesomeProject` is the name of the app):

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   
> > Cannot add task ':app:prepareAwesomeProjectReactNativeLocalizationUnspecifiedLibrary' as a task with that name already exists.

Doing a stacktrace returns the following:

```
(...)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:127)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserDataException: Cannot add task ':app:prepareAwesomeProjectReactNativeLocalizationUnspecifiedLibrary' as a task with that name already exists.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.create(DefaultTaskContainer.java:74)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.create(DefaultTaskContainer.java:97)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.maybeCreatePrepareLibraryTask(DependencyManager.java:227)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.setupPrepareLibraryTask(DependencyManager.java:169)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.processLibraries(DependencyManager.java:162)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.resolveDependencies(DependencyManager.java:157)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.TaskManager.resolveDependencies(TaskManager.java:364)
(...)
```

What is `ReactNativeLocalizationUnspecifiedLibrary`?

I have no clue where to start on how to debug this, and Googling is returning no results. I'm not sure what file(s) are causing the issue.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to resolve this?

Comment: Can you post your gradle build file?

Comment: @RayHunter Wow, newbie error. I'm not sure why, but `compile project(':ReactNativeLocalization')` was in my build.gradle file for some reason, when the correct name was "react-native-localization". I will add an Answer. Thanks for making me look at the build.gradle file. :)

Answer (score 3):

Oops. I just discovered my stupid mistake. I was importing [ReactNativeLocalization](https://github.com/stefalda/ReactNativeLocalization) as:

```
compile project(':ReactNativeLocalization')`
```

in my build.gradle file for some reason. Correct name was "react-native-localization":

```
compile project(':react-native-localization')`
```

Not sure how this happened.